# How do I embed the ViTImageProcessor from HuggingFace's transformers library into a keras Sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to train a TFViTForImageClassification using the .fit function. I want to embed image augmentation and preprocessing within the model. Each one of HuggingFace's ViTs comes with its own feature extractor that preprocesses the images and extracts features for the ViT model.

```
from transformers import TFViTForImageClassification, ViTImageProcessor

model_id = "google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k"
vit = TFViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained(
    pretrained_model_name_or_path=model_id,
    num_labels=k,
    id2label=id2label,
    label2id=label2id
)

vip = ViTImageProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)

class AugmentationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AugmentationLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, images):
        # randomly select an augmentation technique
        choice = tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0, maxval=7, dtype=tf.int32)
        # apply the selected augmentation technique
        images = tf.case([
            (tf.equal(choice, 0), lambda: tf.image.random_brightness(images, max_delta=0.3)),
            (tf.equal(choice, 1), lambda: tf.image.random_contrast(images, lower=0.8, upper=1.2)),
            (tf.equal(choice, 2), lambda: tf.image.random_saturation(images, lower=0.8, upper=1.2)),
            (tf.equal(choice, 3), lambda: tf.image.random_hue(images, max_delta=0.2)),
            (tf.equal(choice, 4), lambda: tf.image.random_flip_left_right(images)),
            (tf.equal(choice, 5), lambda: tf.image.random_flip_up_down(images)),
        ], default=lambda: images)
        return images

class NormalizationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NormalizationLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, images):
        images = tf.convert_to_tensor(vip(images)["pixel_values"])
        return images

# compile model
vt = tf.keras.Sequential(
    layers = [
        AugmentationLayer(),
        NormalizationLayer(),
        vit
    ]
)

vt.compile(
    # optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=args.learning_rate),
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.AdamW(),
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics = [
        tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(1, name="Top1CategoricalAccuracy"),
        tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(5, name="Top5CategoricalAccuracy"),
    ]
)
```

when I pass in some sample images:

```
vt(sample_images)["logits"]
```

it works just fine, I do get the logits tensor.

but when I train the model:

```
vt.fit(x=D_train, validation_data=D_val, epochs=2)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'normalization_layer_3' (type NormalizationLayer).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/tmp/ipykernel_28/3245405357.py", line 7, in call  *
            images = tf.convert_to_tensor(vip(images)["pixel_values"])
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/image_processing_utils.py", line 546, in __call__  *
            return self.preprocess(images, **kwargs)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/vit/image_processing_vit.py", line 217, in preprocess  *
            images = make_list_of_images(images)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/image_utils.py", line 133, in make_list_of_images  *
            if images.ndim == expected_ndims + 1:
    
        AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'normalization_layer_3' (type NormalizationLayer):
      • images=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), dtype=uint8)
```

how can this be done?

I have tried training manually:

```
vip = ViTImageProcessor.from_pretrained(args.model_id)
    # define the training loop
    for epoch in range(run.config["epochs"]):
        print(f'Starting epoch {epoch + 1}/{run.config["epochs"]}')
        # apply gradients
        D_train = D_train.shuffle(D_train.cardinality())
        for batch in D_train:
            # augment images
            images = aug_images(batch[0])
            # compute the loss and gradients for this batch of data
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                images = tf.convert_to_tensor(vip(images)["pixel_values"])
                logits = vit(images, training=True)["logits"]
                loss_value = vit.compiled_loss(batch[1], logits)
            # get the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss
            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, vit.trainable_variables)
            # update the weights of the model using the optimizer
            vit.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, vit.trainable_variables))
            # update the metrics
            vit.compiled_metrics.update_state(batch[1], logits)
```

which works but the training is slow and I cannot use any distributed strategy this way.